# How to temporary store a generated image for download

Tags: django, image, download, temporary

I have written some code for taking an image, and adding some text to it. Currently it just saves the file locally, but I would like it to store the new generated image temporary, so when the session is closed the file is deleted. Also, so in the future multiple users would be able to use the function at the same time, without one user owerwriting another ones image.

My current code is:

```
def Output(request):
    inputValue = request.GET.get('t', '')
    my_image = Image.open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media', 'blank.jpg'))
    title_font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'homepage', 'static', 'homepage', 'Mistral.ttf'), 60)
    title_text = inputValue
    image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
    image_editable.text((45,333), title_text, (0, 0, 0), font=title_font)
    my_image.save(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media', 'result.jpg'))
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'homepage/output.html', {'title': 'Output'})
```

so instead os saving the image locally as result.jpg, how do I save it temporary for a specific session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by modifying what Neeraj Kumar wrote

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
from io import BytesIO
import base64

def get_base64(image):
    img = Image.open(image)
    buffered = BytesIO()
    img.save(buffered, format="PNG")
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue())
    return img_str.decode()

def Output(request):
    inputValue = request.GET.get('t', '')
    my_image = Image.open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media', 'blank.png'))
    title_font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'homepage', 'static', 'homepage', 'Mistral.ttf'), 60)
    title_text = inputValue
    image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
    image_editable.text((45,333), title_text, (0, 0, 0), font=title_font)
    my_image.save(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media', 'result.png'))
    base_image = "data:image/png;base64," + get_base64(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media', 'result.png'))
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'homepage/output.html', {'title': 'Output', 'base_image': base_image})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `base64` concept, Convert your `result.jpg` in `base64` and pass the base64 string through `context`

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

def get_base64(image):
    buffered = BytesIO()
    image.save(buffered, format="JPEG")
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue())
    return "data:image/jpeg;base64," + img_str.decode()


def Output(request):
    inputValue = request.GET.get('t', '')
    my_image = Image.open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media', 'blank.jpg'))
    title_font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'homepage', 'static', 'homepage', 'Mistral.ttf'), 60)
    title_text = inputValue
    image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(my_image)
    image_editable.text((45,333), title_text, (0, 0, 0), font=title_font)
    base_image = get_base64(image_editable)
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'homepage/output.html', {'base_image': base_image})
```

In HTML file

```
<img src="{{base_image}}"/>
```

So you'll not need to save image in system and base64 image will easily work on HTML image tag

Comment: I get the error 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'save'